# Grammar for 看來妳忘了發一個訊息。還是妳有用一些避忌的說話所以中國政府阻擋的

Tags: grammar, mandarin, cantonese

This message was not understood by a friend:

```
看來妳忘了發一個訊息。還是妳有用一些避忌的說話所以中國政府阻擋的。
```

The goal was to say this:

```
It looks like you forgot to send a message. Or else you used some taboo words blocked by the Chinese government.
```

1) Where is the Mandarin grammar wrong for this sentence?

2) Is the Cantonese version different?

Comment: That Chinese sentence is not a good one. Try 要么...要么..., 要么你忘发了，要么就是被屏蔽了。

Comment: @dan thanks for the fast response! how about this: 看來妳忘發了一個訊息。還是那個訊息被屏蔽的。

Comment: still not quite good. I still feel 要么 要么 fits better. 看来，要么是你忘发了，要么就是信息被屏蔽了。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It looks like you forgot to send a message. Or else you used some taboo words blocked by the Chinese government.*
>
> *看來妳忘了發一個訊息。還是妳有用一些避忌的說話所以中國政府阻擋的。*

There are too many different ways to phrase this text, the following is just one of them

> Mandarin: 看來妳忘了發一個訊息。或者妳用了一些避忌的字句，所以被中國政府封殺了？
>
> Cantonese: 睇來妳唔記得發一個訊息。 或者妳用咗一啲避忌嘅字句，所以被中國政府刪咗？

Basically, the only serious grammar mistake is using '的' instead of '了' for final particle.

- '了' indicates 'complete action' , '阻擋了' (blocked) indicates the action of 'blocking' is completed.
- '了' indicates 'change of situation' '阻擋了' (blocked) indicates your message's status changed from 'being allowed' to 'being blocked'
- '的' as a final particle add affirmative tone at the end, Since you started the sentence with "Or else",  '中國政府阻擋的' is out of place here because  "Or else" implies it is just your guess. If the sentence was "用了避忌的說話, 中國政府(是會)阻擋(的)" then it would have no problem.

The other mistakes are mostly poor choice of word. For example, 避忌的(字句) is much better than 避忌的(說話) when it comes to 'texting'. But it doesn't mean using 避忌的(說話) is grammatically incorrect .